# Export all code and output in R to a .txt file?

Tags: r

First time using R.

I was wondering if there was a way to export all the code from RStudio and the output into a .txt file?

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_report_from_r_script.html

This should do it. It's an RMarkdown feature that lets you automatically report your script. It includes the source code and the outputs. I believe there's a MSWord format and a PDF format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sink() and cat() functions in the following way to do it.

```r
# create the output file you will be storing text in. 
sink(file = "textOut.txt")

# convert a script to plain text 
file <- readLines("path to R script")

# compile that text into the .txt file 
cat(file, sep = "\n")

# export the feature to disk
sink()
```